# Any idea why this view is not rotating?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller

I'm working on a photo view controller to display some photos in portrait and landscape view as well. What I did is edit the `-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` orientation with the code below but when testing in xcode (menu hardware > Rotate right) the view does not rotate in landscape. Any thing wrong in what I did ?

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
   return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}
```

The view controller is a part of a tab based iphone app and this view is not root view: is this the problem ?

Comment: [Please don't sign your posts!](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method you want to override is `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation`. Your method signature is missing the `Orientation` on the end.

Comment: I read your answer 10 times and I have no idea what you are trying to say?

Comment: @Rocotilos: check the edit history of this question. OP originally had `shouldAutorotateToInterface`, without the necessary "Orientation" on the end. After I answered, OP edited the question so that my answer now makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

Also check your supported Orientations. For XCode 4 (Project->Summary(Tab)->Supported Device Orientation->Desired Orientations).

Comment: checked Landscape orientations are checked

Answer (score 1):

My first idea would be to just `return true;` to make sure there's no issue with the parameters being passed in / your comparison (it looks good to me but you never know).

Next would be, if this view is not directly attached to the window (or other top-level object if you're using xib's) you may have to also return true in any parent views. For the sake of testing you might just want to overwrite:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIIinterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
   return true;
}
```

for all view (controllers) in the tree.

Answer (score 1):

this could be just a typo, but its not `UIIinterfaceOrientation`, its `UIInterfaceOrientation`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the ViewController in which you implement this method, is the window's rootViewController.
Also, using `return (interfaceOrientation != UIIinterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)` is nicer to read. ;)

Does -shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation get called at all? Try logging something in this method...

Answer (score 0):

Your looking in the wrong place: in your `RootViewController.m` file look for the following code:

```
#elif GAME_AUTOROTATION == kGameAutorotationUIViewController
//
//lots of useless comments
//
return (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation) ); //THIS LINE HERE
```

the line that says return (UIInterface... Portrait) is the line that determines your app's rotating capabilities. You can change this to whatever to allow you to be able to rotate completely, keep it at a certain orientation, or whatever you desire...

also in this

```
 -(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIIinterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
    {
      /* return (interfaceOrientation == UIIinterfaceOrientationPortrait || interfaceOrientation == UIIinterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIIinterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight); */ //GET RID OF ALL THIS CRAP
return true; //do this instead, and if this doesn't work, try return YES;
}
```

Comment: You need to look at your programming courses again! this expression return (interfaceOrientation == UIIinterfaceOrientationPortrait || interfaceOrientation == UIIinterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIIinterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight); is correct

Comment: I'm aware of the fact that it is correct. Just because something is correct doesn't mean it is efficient

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's a type error or edition difference, in my latest Xcode the method is like this:

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation

and it works well, are you missing the "to" of the argument?